# PI column issue

Tags: teradata

I have one issue. I have the below table where 6 columns were taken as PI. However, it is mostly accessed by LXSTATE_ID. The problem is LXSTATE_ID  has around 8 million dups and i don't see any other column which is unique enough to be taken in PI. The table has around 215 million records and i am doing a MINUS between stage and bulk to capture the changed records. Its throwing a spool space issue. What can be done here?

SHOW TABLE GEEDW_D_PLM_ODS_BULK_T.CDR_ODS_LXSTATE_398850F1;

```
CREATE MULTISET TABLE GEEDW_D_PLM_ODS_BULK_T.CDR_ODS_LXSTATE_398850F1 ,NO FALLBACK ,
     NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
     NO AFTER JOURNAL,
     CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,
     DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO
     (
      LXSTATE_ID VARCHAR(4000) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC TITLE 'LXSTATE_ID' NOT NULL,
      BUS_OBJ_OID INTEGER TITLE 'BUS_OBJ_OID',
      MXSTATEREQ_OID INTEGER TITLE 'MXSTATEREQ_OID',
      ACTUAL_DT_GMT TIMESTAMP(0) TITLE 'ACTUAL_DT_GMT',
      START_DT_GMT TIMESTAMP(0) TITLE 'START_DT_GMT',
      END_DT_GMT TIMESTAMP(0) TITLE 'END_DT_GMT',
      DW_LOAD_DATE TIMESTAMP(0) TITLE 'DW_LOAD_DATE',
      DW_CREATED_BY VARCHAR(20) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC TITLE 'DW_CREATED_BY',
      DW_UPDATED_DATE TIMESTAMP(0) TITLE 'DW_UPDATED_DATE',
      DW_UPDATED_BY VARCHAR(20) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC TITLE 'DW_UPDATED_BY')
PRIMARY INDEX CDR_ODS_LXSTATE_398850F1_S_PK ( LXSTATE_ID ,BUS_OBJ_OID ,
MXSTATEREQ_OID ,ACTUAL_DT_GMT ,START_DT_GMT ,END_DT_GMT );
```

Here is the MINUS query:
HERE VT_LXSTATE_398850F1 is a volatile table where the changed records are being captured.

```
INSERT INTO VT_LXSTATE_398850F1 
(
LXSTATE_ID,
BUS_OBJ_OID,
MXSTATEREQ_OID,
ACTUAL_DT_GMT,
START_DT_GMT,
END_DT_GMT
)
SELECT
LXSTATE_ID,
BUS_OBJ_OID,
MXSTATEREQ_OID,
ACTUAL_DT_GMT,
START_DT_GMT,
END_DT_GMT 
FROM GEEDW_PLP_S.CDR_ODS_LXSTATE_398850F1_S 
MINUS
SELECT
LXSTATE_ID,                    
BUS_OBJ_OID,                   
MXSTATEREQ_OID,                
ACTUAL_DT_GMT,                 
START_DT_GMT,                  
END_DT_GMT                
FROM GEEDW_PLM_ODS_BULK_T.CDR_ODS_LXSTATE_398850F1;
```

Below is the explain plan for the insert:
Below is the explain plan for the INSERT.

```
Explain INSERT INTO VT_LXSTATE_398850F1 
(
LXSTATE_ID,
BUS_OBJ_OID,
MXSTATEREQ_OID,
ACTUAL_DT_GMT,
START_DT_GMT,
END_DT_GMT
)
SELECT
LXSTATE_ID,
BUS_OBJ_OID,
MXSTATEREQ_OID,
ACTUAL_DT_GMT,
START_DT_GMT,
END_DT_GMT 
FROM GEEDW_D_PLP_S.CDR_ODS_LXSTATE_398850F1_S_BKP 
MINUS
SELECT
LXSTATE_ID,                    
BUS_OBJ_OID,                   
MXSTATEREQ_OID,                
ACTUAL_DT_GMT,                 
START_DT_GMT,                  
END_DT_GMT                
FROM GEEDW_D_PLM_ODS_BULK_T.CDR_ODS_LXSTATE_398850F1_BKP;

  1) First, we lock a distinct GEEDW_D_PLP_S."pseudo table" for read on
     a RowHash to prevent global deadlock for
     GEEDW_D_PLP_S.CDR_ODS_LXSTATE_398850F1_S_BKP.
  2) Next, we lock a distinct GEEDW_D_PLM_ODS_BULK_T."pseudo table" for
     read on a RowHash to prevent global deadlock for
     GEEDW_D_PLM_ODS_BULK_T.CDR_ODS_LXSTATE_398850F1_BKP.
  3) We lock GEEDW_D_PLP_S.CDR_ODS_LXSTATE_398850F1_S_BKP for read, and
     we lock GEEDW_D_PLM_ODS_BULK_T.CDR_ODS_LXSTATE_398850F1_BKP for
     read.
  4) We execute the following steps in parallel.
       1) We do an all-AMPs RETRIEVE step from
          GEEDW_D_PLP_S.CDR_ODS_LXSTATE_398850F1_S_BKP by way of an
          all-rows scan with no residual conditions into Spool 2
          (all_amps), which is redistributed by the hash code of (
          GEEDW_D_PLP_S.CDR_ODS_LXSTATE_398850F1_S_BKP.END_DT_GMT,
          GEEDW_D_PLP_S.CDR_ODS_LXSTATE_398850F1_S_BKP.START_DT_GMT,
          GEEDW_D_PLP_S.CDR_ODS_LXSTATE_398850F1_S_BKP.ACTUAL_DT_GMT,
          GEEDW_D_PLP_S.CDR_ODS_LXSTATE_398850F1_S_BKP.MXSTATEREQ_OID,
          GEEDW_D_PLP_S.CDR_ODS_LXSTATE_398850F1_S_BKP.BUS_OBJ_OID,
          GEEDW_D_PLP_S.CDR_ODS_LXSTATE_398850F1_S_BKP.LXSTATE_ID) to
          all AMPs.  Then we do a SORT to order Spool 2 by row hash and
          the sort key in spool field1 eliminating duplicate rows.  The
          input table will not be cached in memory, but it is eligible
          for synchronized scanning.  The result spool file will not be
          cached in memory.  The size of Spool 2 is estimated with no
          confidence to be 322,724,040 rows (1,755,618,777,600 bytes).
          The estimated time for this step is 1 hour and 55 minutes.
       2) We do an all-AMPs RETRIEVE step from
          GEEDW_D_PLM_ODS_BULK_T.CDR_ODS_LXSTATE_398850F1_BKP by way of
          an all-rows scan with no residual conditions into Spool 3
          (all_amps), which is redistributed by the hash code of (
          GEEDW_D_PLM_ODS_BULK_T.CDR_ODS_LXSTATE_398850F1_BKP.END_DT_GMT,
          GEEDW_D_PLM_ODS_BULK_T.CDR_ODS_LXSTATE_398850F1_BKP.START_DT_GMT,
          GEEDW_D_PLM_ODS_BULK_T.CDR_ODS_LXSTATE_398850F1_BKP.ACTUAL_DT_GMT,
          GEEDW_D_PLM_ODS_BULK_T.CDR_ODS_LXSTATE_398850F1_BKP.MXSTATEREQ_OID,
          GEEDW_D_PLM_ODS_BULK_T.CDR_ODS_LXSTATE_398850F1_BKP.BUS_OBJ_OID,
          GEEDW_D_PLM_ODS_BULK_T.CDR_ODS_LXSTATE_398850F1_BKP.LXSTATE_ID)
          to all AMPs.  Then we do a SORT to order Spool 3 by row hash
          and the sort key in spool field1 eliminating duplicate rows.
          The input table will not be cached in memory, but it is
          eligible for synchronized scanning.  The result spool file
          will not be cached in memory.  The size of Spool 3 is
          estimated with no confidence to be 161,362,020 rows (
          877,809,388,800 bytes).  The estimated time for this step is
          56 minutes and 33 seconds.
  5) We do an all-AMPs JOIN step from Spool 2 (Last Use) by way of an
     all-rows scan, which is joined to Spool 3 (Last Use) by way of an
     all-rows scan.  Spool 2 and Spool 3 are joined using an exclusion
     merge join, with a join condition of ("Field_1 = Field_1").  The
     result goes into Spool 1 (all_amps), which is built locally on the
     AMPs.  The size of Spool 1 is estimated with no confidence to be
     242,043,030 rows (1,316,714,083,200 bytes).  The estimated time
     for this step is 9 minutes and 11 seconds.
  6) We do an all-AMPs RETRIEVE step from Spool 1 (Last Use) by way of
     an all-rows scan into Spool 4 (all_amps), which is redistributed
     by the hash code of (
     GEEDW_D_PLP_S.CDR_ODS_LXSTATE_398850F1_S_BKP.LXSTATE_ID,
     GEEDW_D_PLP_S.CDR_ODS_LXSTATE_398850F1_S_BKP.MXSTATEREQ_OID) to
     all AMPs.  Then we do a SORT to order Spool 4 by row hash.  The
     result spool file will not be cached in memory.  The size of Spool
     4 is estimated with no confidence to be 242,043,030 rows (
     331,114,865,040 bytes).  The estimated time for this step is 59
     minutes and 11 seconds.
  7) We do an all-AMPs MERGE into "502332938".VT_LXSTATE_398850F1 from
     Spool 4 (Last Use).  The size is estimated with no confidence to
     be 242,043,030 rows.  **The estimated time for this step is 19 hours
     and 53 minutes.**
  8) We spoil the parser's dictionary cache for the table.
  9) Finally, we send out an END TRANSACTION step to all AMPs involved
     in processing the request.
  -> No rows are returned to the user as the result of statement 1.
```

Comment: I tried taking other columns in the PI the distribution looks good but the query is throwing spool issue when inserting in the Volatile table

Comment: Does the Volatile Table have a PI matching the tables participating in the MINUS? What step in the EXPLAIN for the INSERT statement is the querying running out of spool? Can you post the EXPLAIN output for the INSERT statement?

Comment: Yes the volatile table has a PI matching with the tables participating in the MINUS.

Comment: The redistribution steps in 4(1) and 4(2) seem to indicate something with the PI of the tables is amiss. Then you have another redistribution in step 6 before the merge of the resulting spool file into the VT. These redistributions seem suspect. Do you know Which step is spooling out?

Comment: Yes, the PI is a problem. But, i don't have any other columns which are unique to be taken as PI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A MINUS is always DISTINCT, that's why there are "eliminating duplicate rows" steps.

MINUS ALL might be a bit better, but I's prefer a NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT 
LXSTATE_ID,
BUS_OBJ_OID,
MXSTATEREQ_OID,
ACTUAL_DT_GMT,
START_DT_GMT,
END_DT_GMT 
FROM GEEDW_PLP_S.CDR_ODS_LXSTATE_398850F1_S AS t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
 (
   SELECT *
   FROM GEEDW_PLM_ODS_BULK_T.CDR_ODS_LXSTATE_398850F1 AS t2
   WHERE t1.LXSTATE_ID     = t2.LXSTATE_ID
     AND t1.BUS_OBJ_OID    = t2.BUS_OBJ_OID
     AND t1.MXSTATEREQ_OID = t2.MXSTATEREQ_OID
     AND t1.ACTUAL_DT_GMT  = t2.ACTUAL_DT_GMT
     AND t1.START_DT_GMT   = t2.START_DT_GMT
     AND t1.END_DT_GMT     = t2.END_DT_GMT
  )
```

For every NULLABLE column you must add a condition:

```
(t1.LXSTATE_ID    =t2.LXSTATE_ID OR (t1.LXSTATE_ID IS NULL AND t2.LXSTATE_ID IS NULL))
```

This will result in an exclusion join on the PI.

If you don't need to match on NULL a MERGE should perform better:

```
MERGE INTO GEEDW_PLM_ODS_BULK_T.CDR_ODS_LXSTATE_398850F1 AS tgt
USING GEEDW_PLP_S.CDR_ODS_LXSTATE_398850F1_S AS src
ON  tgt.LXSTATE_ID    =src.LXSTATE_ID
AND tgt.BUS_OBJ_OID   =src.BUS_OBJ_OID
AND tgt.MXSTATEREQ_OID=src.MXSTATEREQ_OID
AND tgt.ACTUAL_DT_GMT =src.ACTUAL_DT_GMT
AND tgt.START_DT_GMT  =src.START_DT_GMT
AND tgt.END_DT_GMT    =src.END_DT_GMT
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
INSERT (
LXSTATE_ID,
BUS_OBJ_OID,
MXSTATEREQ_OID,
ACTUAL_DT_GMT,
START_DT_GMT,
END_DT_GMT  
) VALUES (
src.LXSTATE_ID,
src.BUS_OBJ_OID,
src.MXSTATEREQ_OID,
src.ACTUAL_DT_GMT,
src.START_DT_GMT,
src.END_DT_GMT  
)
```